# Страница справочного центра "На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?" переведено с мета.SE

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Очевидно, что вопросы о рекламе или карьере SO - оффтопики на ru.SO.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мы постарались предоставить базовый перевод всех страниц с MSE. Идея была в том, чтобы предоставить базовую страницу, которую сможет изменять сообщество. На сколько я могу видеть, на Stack Overflow и Meta Stack Exchange существует порядка 6 различных разделов, один из которых "На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы". Stack Overflow на русском может иметь отличный от Stack Overflow набор допустимых тем, как результат, именно сообщество должно принять участие в выборе тех тематик, какие мы будем рассматривать на форуме.